# how to generate a pdf in php

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

i used the following code....

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

when i run it on the server..i get the following error...

```
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required 'fpdf.php'
```

should i include some other extenal libraries to make it work...
my server is currently runnin on php 5.2.17...

Comment: error says it all your missing `fpdf.php` file in the requested require path.

Comment: check your path of the file fpdf.php is correct.

Comment: my bad....but i even tried the path "../fpdf/fpdf.php" but even then the i'm getting same error....shud i download sum other external lib for making use of pdf functions or not....if not shud i tinker sumthin in the php module...kindly guide me

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about  a very individual problem without given any further reference to commons in programming in a useful manner while using an outdated Software that is not generally supported any longer. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please enter the correct path for the require function e.g. `require('fpdf/fpdf.php')`
On your code your page that creates pdf and the fpdf.php was not on the same directory. Locate first your fpdf.php directory and include it in your page.
Please refer here. `http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php`

Comment: my bad....but i even tried the path "../fpdf/fpdf.php" but even then the i'm getting same error....shud i download sum other external lib for making use of pdf functions or not....if not shud i tinker sumthin in the php module...kindly guide me

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i could not find any proper link that said v have to **DOWNLOAD** a file. So thanks to above answers. I found the exact file i needed.
http://www.fpdf.org/en/dl.php?v=17&f=zip
this link downloads a zip file. Unzip the file n place the files in the apache document root inside a folder. Now create your own file to customize the pdf file n include the 'fpdf.php' in your file as so...

```
require('fpdf.php'); //or
require('../fpdf.php') //according to the file location
```

cheers. Happy Coding :)